# Limiting woocommerce line_total decimal length

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, order

I am trying to get line_total woocommerce price, but i just cant figure out how to deal with number of decimals. It is now showing price with 4 decimals like 5.5444$ and i want it to show max 2 decimals, like 5.54$.

Does anyone know what am i doing wrong? I have no problems with orger_total price which is showing correctly with just 2 decimals.

```
$myID = 2859;
$myorder = new WC_Order($myID);

    foreach ($myorder->get_items('line_item') as $item) {
        $Data = $Data.OrderLine($item["name"], $item["line_total"], $item["line_tax"], $item["qty"], "piece", "x");
    }
```

Is there a way to limit `$item["line_total"]`to max 2 decimal numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) the decimal to two digit as per your requirement.

```
$myID = 2859;
$myorder = new WC_Order($myID);

    foreach ($myorder->get_items('line_item') as $item) {
         $rounded_total = round($item["line_total"],2);// allow 2 decimal and avoid further
        $Data = $Data.OrderLine($item["name"], $rounded_total, $item["line_tax"], $item["qty"], "piece", "x");
    }
```